# How to Retrieve Last Record in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table name `Data` with fields
`Surmane`, `Name`, `Timestamp`, `PaidMoney`, `ChangAmmount`, `Address`, `Store`

I want to have as result of a query the last record (DESC `Timestamp` Limit 1) of each person (group by `Surname`, `Name`) with the `PaidMoney`,`ChangeAmmount`, `Address`, `Store`

For example the result must be

```
Jones, Jim, 1290596796, 220.00, 0.25, 5th Avenue 120, Some Store1  
Kojak, Ian, 1290596890, 1000.00, 50.25, Derek Avenue 1020, Some Store2
```

For each combination of Surname, Name must present the last record.

I try to do this with:

```
select `Surname`, 
       `Name`, 
        max(date_format(from_unixtime(`Timestamp`),'%Y/%m/%d - %T')) AS `dateTime`,
       `PaidMoney`, 
       `ChangAmmount`, 
       `Address`, 
       `Store` 
from `Data` 
group by `Surname`, `Name`;
```

No good cause this doesn't show correct data.....

Please Help...

Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1.surname,
       t1.name,
       from_unixtime(t1.timestamp,'%Y/%m/%d - %T') as datetime,
       t1.PaidMoney, 
       t1.ChangAmmount, 
       t1.Address, 
       t1.Store 
from table as t1
inner join (select concat_ws(' ',name,surname) as n,max(timestamp) as timestamp 
        from table
        group by name,surname) as t2
on t1.timestamp = t2.timestamp and concat_ws(' ',t1.name,surname) = t2.n
```

Your table contains redundant datas of names and surnames.
It would be better if you put these datas in another table and refer to them using people id.
Moreover without an id, the use of concat will slow down the join performance, even if you would have an index.

edit.

```
create view my_view as
select * from table t1
where timestamp = (select max(timestamp) from table as t2
                   where concat_ws(' ',t1.name,t1.surname) = concat_ws(' ',t2.name,t2.surname))
```

Comment: Thank you so much.....!!! My second problem now is that I can't make this View.... I get the message "View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause"....

Answer (score 0):

You should add `order by timestamp DESC` to your query and change the `max(...)` part to `timestamp`.

Comment: How does this ensure that the correct store and payment are included?

Answer (score 0):

You could do a subquery (ie. a nested SELECT) to get the max(date stuff) for each person, but that wouldn't be very efficient, according this page, which suggests another way that might be helpful:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html